# AES GCM non-EVP implementation in openssl?

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, aes-gcm

Does openssl have a "raw" (non-EVP) interface to do AES GCM encryption and decryption?  I'm looking for something comparable to AES_cbc_encrypt() or DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt(), but for AES GCM.  I found the openssl EVP interfaces for AES GCM but I can't find any information on any non-EVP interface.

I understand the EVP interface has many advantages for general purpose use, but I'm doing some tests where a non-EVP interface would be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Once I was looking for it and I couldn't find any non-EVP implementation of it. According to the OpenSSL site 'the enc program does not support authenticated encryption modes like CCM and GCM'.
But it seems AES GCM only supported in TLS v1.2 (according to 'https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html').